# ViewChild/ViewChildren and class selector in Angular

Tags: angular

I use Angular 9 and use `ViewChild` and `ViewChildren` to select elements that are present in my HTML file. Do any of these two functions support class selectors? As far as I can see, they only work for IDs.

```
@ViewChild('.foo') Foo: ElementRef;
```

Any alternative would also be good, just during the execution of a function I would like to have access to all 'Foo' objects.

https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren

Thank you!

Comment: what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: I would like to get the `nativeElement` of HTML element**S** through a class selector. ANd I thought ViewChild/ViewChildren could help me there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `ViewChild` doesn't support class selector. To grab an HTML element, you can use `template reference variable` as shown below,

```
<div #refElement> ... </div>         //  # refElement is a template reference variable
```

.ts

```
 @ViewChild('refElement') el: ElementRef;


// viewchild instance will be available in or after ngAfterviewInit life cycle hook

 ngAfterViewInit(){  
       console.log(this.el.nativeElement); 
 }
```

Answer (score 7):

`ViewChild` or `ViewChildren` only works with `references`(e.x. `#element` in html).
If you want to select by classes, you could use `ElementRef`.
`ElementRef` will let you access the template of the component.
So you can use native javascript function like `getElementsByClassName` after you got the component template as html element.

```
constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

...

this.elementRef.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName('foo')
```

Comment: It should be with the dot: this.elementRef.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName('foo')