# Not able to bind change or ngModelChange to ng-select using addEventListener

Tags: javascript, angular, addeventlistener, angular-ngselect, angular-ngmodelchange

I have a `formgroup` with multiple controls like input, `ng-select`s etc.
Now, **I want to get notified whenever user changes value of some specific inputs and `ng-select`s**.
I don't want to do it via `valueChanges` subscribe due to some reasons.

For sample scenario, I have created one input and one `ng-select` control and **binding change event to input and `ng-select` using `addEventListener`**. It's **working fine for inputs but not for `ng-select`s**.
I have tried changing the event to `ngModelChange` for `ng-select` but still it's not working.

Also, I **wanted to pick the common elements using `viewchildren` via common class** `abc` but the element list is not coming when picking via class.

Below is the code.
**HTML**

```
<form action="" [formGroup]="doomsForm">
  <input class="abc" type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" formControlName="name"
  #qwe />
  <ng-select
    [items]="ageArr"
    formControlName="age"
    placeholder="Enter Age"
    #qwe
    class="abc"
  ></ng-select>
</form>
```

**TS Code**

```
@ViewChildren('qwe', { read: ElementRef }) commonElements!: QueryList<ElementRef>;
@ViewChildren('.abc', { read: ElementRef }) commonElements!: QueryList<ElementRef>; 
// above line for view children  using .abc class is not working

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.ValueChange();
}
ValueChange() {
const elements = this.commonElements.toArray();

// Add event listeners dynamically
elements.forEach((element, index) => {
  if (element.nativeElement.tagName === 'INPUT') {
    element.nativeElement.addEventListener('change', () => {
      // Handle change for input or ng-select elements
      this.onInputChange(element.nativeElement.value, index);
    });
  } else if (element.nativeElement.tagName === 'NG-SELECT') {
    element.nativeElement.addEventListener('ngModelChange', () => {
      this.onSelectChange(element.nativeElement, index);
      // }
    });
  }
});
}
onInputChange(value: string, index: number) {
  console.log(`Input ${index + 1} value changed:`, value);
}

onSelectChange(element: any, index: number) {
  console.log(`Ng-select ${index + 1} value changed:`, element.selectedItems);
}
```

Comment: The `ViewChildren` selector only works via references, you can't use it for class names. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62959389/viewchild-viewchildren-and-class-selector-in-angular).  Also it's generally a bad idea to mix Angular with vanilla JS event listeners like that.

Comment: @ChrisBarr, thanks for the clarification regarding ViewChildren selector.
Is there any other approach to dynamically add event listeners to angular elements?

Comment: Well you can add a [`@HostListener`](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener) decorator on a function, but that usually only applies to the component host youa re currently in, or the entire window. Is there a reason you don't just use a `<ng select (change)="onSelectChange()"` right on the element to call a function? That seems like the simplest solution by far, and the standard Angular way of doing things.

Comment: @ChrisBarr, I opted not to use the change event in HTML because the project involves a substantial number of controls. Therefore, my objective was to dynamically bind the change event to all of these controls.

Comment: I would advise against that because you are using Angular, so you should actually use the framework instead of trying to outsmart it. Mixing Angular with non-angular event binding is confusing, non-standard, and might not even behave as you intend it to